# R Shiny Progress Box

Tags: css, r, shiny, progress

I am working on a shiny app and have implemented my progress bar and modified it how it wanted using `.progress`, `.progess-bar` and `.progress-text` within my CSS. I have it nearly how I want, but I just need to get rid of the grey popup box with the x (see attached image).

[image: Progress bar]

I've tried a variety of different CSS combinations and have got nowhere. Does anyone know the CSS ID for this box?

Example:

ui:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  includeCSS("www/styles.css"),

  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),

  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))
```

server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$plot <- renderPlot({
input$goPlot 

dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
  n <- 1000

  for (i in 1:n) {
    dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))

    incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))

  }
})

plot(dat$x, dat$y)
})
}
```

css

```
.progress{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:50px;
  left:25%;
  width:50%;
}

.progress-bar{
  background-color:#000;
}

.progress-text{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:60px;
  left:25%;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: @HubertL example now included above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS, it will hide the notification:

```
.shiny-notification{
  position:fixed;
  left:-100px;
  width:0px;
}
```

Comment: As a follow up, is there a way to position or style bars differently by placing them in certain divs and then altering the CSS? I've seen a lot of 'make you're own' bar information, but I'd ideally like to stick with the `withProgress` and `incProgress` if possible.